# Uploading files in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, upload

I am trying to make a site where users can upload files. I have some basic parameters (like making sure they're logged in, etc) above this code. I have narrowed down where my error is. Whenever I try to upload a file, it loads for a long time (even when it's just a small JPG), and displays nothing. I've looked through a bunch of previous questions, but they don't really help.

HTML

```
<form name="contact" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple><br><div id="adder"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    //Make sure we have a filepath
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)){ 
            set_time_limit(0);  
            echo "Thanks for your submission! Your file was uploaded.;  
        }
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the `echo`, and a couple of closing braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your this line:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple><br><div id="adder"></div>
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple><br><div id="adder"></div>
```

and please write the proper code cause incomplete information will take people away for actual reason for the code to not work.( you did not close the for loop there)

also I am assuming you have checked the POST request using $_POST[] before saving anything to make sure someone actually submitted the form.

Comment: Yes, I checked the post. What do you mean "close the loop"?

Comment: Oh. Nevermind. Yes, I did close the for-loop; I just forgot to type it in my question.